# Is there any git commands that I can get all files (like a 'snapshop') in a commit though some files were already commited?

Tags: git

If I have a repo contains such files:

```
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
d.txt
```

When I do some changes and commits, and execute some command like:

```
git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r 32f38b2a
```

It will show the file name or some other info of the files changed in the commit '**32f38b2a**':

```
a.txt
b.txt
```

Are there any way I can get a 'snapshot' in a commit, which contains all file(and the hash) when the commit '**32f38b2a**' was created?

```
a.txt <hash>
b.txt <hash>
c.txt <hash>
d.txt <hash>
```

> some 'tree' commands will contains the deleted file, and I just want the exact files in one commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commits already *are* snapshots.  To list the files inside a commit, use `git ls-tree`, for which you need the `-r` (recursive) option to look inside directories.

(For a less verbose variant, use `git show <commit-hash-id>:`, including the final colon, but this does not show the blob hash IDs.)